# Mobile Push notification not working debug mode iOS

Tags: mobilepush, mobilepush-ios

I've created two mobile push apps in MC, one for production and the other for development.
For both of them i've uploaded the same .p8 file and configuration, except for the APNs Environment.
The problem is that i can receive push only on release mode.
Am I missing something here?
Do I need to create another Key in my Apple Developer account?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That is correct, you only need one p8 file that can be used for both apps. You will notice the toggle that you see on the right hand side in your image provided says `development` or `production`. This setting correlates to sending to dev or production APNS environments. So for your mobile push app that is being used for development, set the APNS environment to `Development`, and the Production app should be set to `Production`.

Comment: Hi Skyler, I've done exactly that but i continue to have the same problem on debug mode.
The contact is getting registered and everything seems ok, the problem is that when i send the push notification it never reaches the device.

Comment: Do you also have a p12 certificate uploaded to the Marketing Cloud and is it expired?

Comment: Bill, that was exactly the problem. I created another app from scratch with the toggle on development and it worked!
Thank you both!